# Batch file - How to find quotes in a string?

Tags: windows, batch-file

When given an environment variable that may or may not be quoted I need to remove the quotes.

For example, I may be given:

1. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`
2. `JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144"`

I am trying to use `findstr` and it seems to work well from cmd.exe but not from my batch file. This is what I have in `test1.bat`:

```
@echo off

echo.%JAVA_HOME% | findstr \^" 1>nul
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    echo Found Quotes
)
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo No Quotes found
)
```

The problem I have is that the `ERRORLEVEL` always seems to be `0` and I always get the message "Found Quotes" when I run `test1.bat`.

I have this code to remove quotes `for /f "delims=" %%G IN (%JAVA_HOME%) DO SET JAVA_HOME=%%G` which works find, but only when there are quotes, hence needing to get the above `findstr` conditions working correctly.

Comment: Three answers till now and every one handles a different aspect. The main problem with your code is that you've to compare the [highest errorlevel first](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) You could avoid this with conditional execution: `echo:%AJVA_HOME%| findstr ^" >nul 2>&1 && (echo Quotes found)||(echo no quotes found)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files already have the ability to remove quotes on `for`-loop variables like `%%G` in your example, so you do not need any of that `findstr` logic.  The reason why your `for` doesn't work is because you're not quoting the `%JAVA_HOME%`.  You always have to quote arguments that have spaces.

From `help for`, the syntax is:

> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command
>   [command-parameters]

And on automatic variables like `%%G`, the tilde operator removes quotes if they are present.

From `help for`:

> In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
>   enhanced.     You can now use the following optional syntax:
>
> ```
>   %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> ```

So with these 2 pieces of information, change your `for` loop to this to remove quotes from `%JAVA_HOME%`.

```
for /f "delims=" %%G IN ("%JAVA_HOME%") DO SET "JAVA_HOME=%%~G"
```

Comment: Thanks that works lovely, although I had to change `"JAVA_HOME=%%~G\"` to `"JAVA_HOME=%%~G"`

Comment: @adamretter:  Oops, I thought I had copied and pasted that, but it looks like I introduced that typo myself.  I edited the answer to remove the slash.

Answer (score 1):

You typically have to test for other values for ERRORLEVEL before testing for 0, IIRC. This works perfectly for me:

```
@echo off

echo.%JAVA_HOME% | findstr \^" 1>nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo No quotes found
    goto :eof
)
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (
    echo Found quotes
)
```

NOTE: Removing the `goto :eof` means you get both lines output by `echo` if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
SET "java_home=%java_home:"=%"
SET j
ECHO -------------------------------------------
SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144"
SET "java_home=%java_home:"=%"
SET j

GOTO :EOF
```

Either way, `java_home` ends up "nude".